# Why Spark not serializable exception occurs when changing RDD to DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am using structured streaming and following code works

```
val j = new Jedis() // an redis client which is not serializable.

xx.writeStream.foreachBatch{(batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => {
  j.xtrim(...)... // call function of Jedis here
  batchDF.rdd.mapPartitions(...)
}}
```

But following code throws an exception, `object not serializable (class: redis.clients.jedis.Jedis, value: redis.clients.jedis.Jedis@a8e0378)`

The code has only one place change (change RDD to DataFrame):

```
val j = new Jedis() // an redis client which is not serializable.

xx.writeStream.foreachBatch{(batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => {
  j.xtrim(...)... // call function of Jedis here
  batchDF.mapPartitions(...)  // only change is change batchDF.rdd to batchDF
}}
```

My `Jedis` code should be executed on driver and never reach executor. I suppose Spark RDD and DataFrame should have similar APIS? Why this happens?

---

I used ctrl to go into the lower level code. The `batchDF.mapPartitions` goes to

```
  @Experimental
  @InterfaceStability.Evolving
  def mapPartitions[U : Encoder](func: Iterator[T] => Iterator[U]): Dataset[U] = 
  {
    new Dataset[U](
      sparkSession,
      MapPartitions[T, U](func, logicalPlan),
      implicitly[Encoder[U]])
  }
```

and `batchDF.rdd.mapPartitions` goes to

```
    def mapPartitions[U: ClassTag](
      f: Iterator[T] => Iterator[U],
      preservesPartitioning: Boolean = false): RDD[U] = withScope {
    val cleanedF = sc.clean(f)
    new MapPartitionsRDD(
      this,
      (context: TaskContext, index: Int, iter: Iterator[T]) => cleanedF(iter),
      preservesPartitioning)
  }
```

My Spark version is 2.4.3.

My simplest version of code below, and I just found something else...

```
val j = new Jedis() // an redis client which is not serializable.

xx.writeStream.foreachBatch{(batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => {
  j.xtrim(...)... // call function of Jedis here
  batchDF.mapPartitions(x => {
    val arr = x.grouped(2).toArray // this line matters
  })
  // only change is change batchDF.rdd to batchDF
}}
```

Comment: Dataset calls to `val deserialized = CatalystSerde.deserialize[T](child)` while RDD - `ClosureCleaner.clean(f, checkSerializable)`
There might be some differences involved downstream

Comment: @morsik I think yours should be the right answer

Comment: could you provide a whole stack trace and/or reproducible example. I've tried to come up with simplified version, but everything works w/o any exceptions. Are you 100% sure you don't use Jedis object inside `mapPartitions`?

Comment: @morsik I have posted the simplest version of code. And on the way of that I found what really matters here... `val arr = x.grouped(2).toArray` this code works in `batchDF.rdd.mapPartitions` but does not work in `batchDF.mapPartitions`, create a arbitrary spark session and just add this code I think you can reproduce the error. And I believe this code does nothing with `Jedis` object

Comment: @morsik changing `toArray` to `toString` the same error occurs. I think the question could be changed to "Why operations in mapPartition of DataFrame have connections with driver code"?

Comment: I have no errors running this code (note, I don't use streaming context).
On the other hand, not sure of grouping iterator inside `mapPartitions` makes any sense from the logical standpoint. `mapPartitions` is lazy transformation, while `foreachBatch` is Spark action.
What are you trying to achieve with this `map` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [this DataFrame api implementation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.scala#L1426)

internally its calling rdd.mapPartitions of your function.

```
     /**
       * Returns a new RDD by applying a function to each partition of this DataFrame.
       * @group rdd
       * @since 1.3.0
       */
      def mapPartitions[R: ClassTag](f: Iterator[Row] => Iterator[R]): RDD[R] = {
        rdd.mapPartitions(f)
      }
```

There is no difference some where else you might have done mistake.

AFAIK, Ideally this should be the way

```
 batchDF.mapPartitions { yourparition =>
// better to create a JedisPool and take object rather than new Jedis
 val j = new Jedis() 
val result = yourparition.map {
// do some process here
}

j.close // release and take care of connections/ resources here
result
}
}
```

Comment: I want to operate `val j = new Jedis` on spark driver but not in executor. Is there any potential risk in my version code?

Comment: @Ram Ghadiyaram your reference is for Spark 1.6

Comment: @Ram Ghadiyaram I posted my code jump-to and my version is 2.4.3, and I am not sure how it is in newest version. And if your code is 1.6 then the newest code should be more consistent to mine.

Comment: By the way I am very sure that the only one difference in two code is `batchDF.rdd.mapPartitions` and `batchDF.mapPartitions`